# How to Check Special Data Sqlite Database in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've created a database with databaseHelper class Kotlin that it included onCreate / upgrade / insert / readAlldatas functions that these are run correctly but I want have another function that get special data in databaseHelper class and check it in MainActivity with if statement that if this special data existed in database do something

thx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your code and what you have tried so far! This way people can help you and not code for you. If you need a guide on [How To Ask a question here you go!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    fun returnDbIntValue(myString : String): Int{
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DB_TABLE_NAME WHERE SOME_DB_COLUN_NAME = '$myString'", null).count
}
```

Using similar function you can check if the data is in data base or not.
 inside of main activity you can do this:

```
    val dbHelper = MyDbHelper(this)
if(dbHelper.returnDbIntValue(yourStringOrOtherData)==0) {
//this will happen if DB does not have such value saved
} else {
//this will happen if DB have such value saved
}
```